# How to properly load google map api in JSFiddle ?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

- I already registered my project with Google to get an API_KEY.
- I already enable the Google MAP API in the API console. See here

[image]

- I already set the referred to my JSFiddle Account.

  `[ http://jsfiddle.net/bheng/* ]`

Here the link [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/bheng/9wc30ndf/)

I am not sure why, it didn't load the map while it should.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not including the Google Maps Javascript API. Note that you don't *need* a key (particularly for jsfiddle).  Add this to the "External Resources":

```
 https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js
```

And add JQuery under "Frameworks & Extensions":

http://jsfiddle.net/9wc30ndf/2/

But you need to read the message also (you are missing the "q=")

http://jsfiddle.net/9wc30ndf/3/

Comment: I got it from the HTML part `<h1><span id="address"> 410 walker street Lowell MA 01851 </span></h1>` like this `var q=encodeURIComponent($('#address').text());`

Comment: check out this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/pkjq1hrb/). How come's it's work ? We both have almost identical code except the API_KEY.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `*fiddle.jshell.net/bheng/*` as the referrer expression for your browser-API-key since jsfiddle loads the JS sources from this domain (see referer request-header).